# Границы понятий "мавзолей" и "гробница"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли вместилище, в котором спит Ленин, назвать гробницей, а помещение, в котором похоронен фараон — мавзолеем?

Comment: А что это за вредитель Вам минус поставил? Исправляю своим плюсом. Хороший вопрос. Вообще, изначально мавзолей – это сооружение, в котором собирался упокоиться царь Мавсол, это Малая Азия. Согласно словарю М. Фасмера, слово "гробница" восходит к европейским корням. Значения, определённо слились сегодня. Даже если найти исторические отличия, сегодня это знание больше навредит, чем поможет понять материалы по истории, археологии или архитектуре. Думаю, мы вправе употреблять слова как синонимы. В случае Ленина, скорее, речь о привычке к такому названию, нежели о строгом определении.

Answer (score 2):

Постараюсь дать вменяемый ответ и воспроизведу мысль из комментария: согласно словарю М. Фасмера, гробница восходит к европейским корням. С той или иной разницей оно обозначает сооружение, если угодно, здание (хотя не всегда), где хранят останки. Гробница — не конкретизированное, а общее слово, которым можно описать широкий диапазон сооружений от египетских пирамид до фамильных склепов. Мы не должны впасть в заблуждение: гробница — это вовсе не место, где хранится гроб. Здесь, скорее, параллель со словом "грести", а "гроб" в его нынешнем значении — производное от этого корня.

Гробницы не всегда содержали гробы, и более того — гробница может быть даже не зданием, а, например, земляной насыпью, курганом. Поэтому "сооружение" — наиболее точное определение.

Мавзолей "пришёл" к нам с Востока. Царь Мавсол построил для себя одно из Семи Чудес Света — коллаж из архитектурных элементов разных культур его времени: Египта, Греции, Аравии. Поэтому Мавозолей, он один. Но со временем это слово стали употреблять в отношении других построек, вероятно, выстроенных в подражание усыпальнице Мавсола. Хотя трудно выделить однозначные критерии, по которым мы можем определить именно мавзолей (да и цель такая не стоит), он, с точки зрения наших традиций, в любом случае попадает в категорию "гробницы".

Так что мавзолей — это один из видов гробницы, коей может быть и курган, и пирамида, и склеп, и, вероятно, даже колумбарий. Так что Ленин действительно лежит в гробнице, которая, видимо, отвечает архитектурными признаками современному представлению о мавзолеях.

От себя добавлю, что сложно судить о том, что является мавзолеем, а то что нет, поскольку строение Мавсола не сохранилось до наших дней. Какие признаки этого сооружения для нас первичны в определении, а какие не обязательны? Тут не может быть правил. Скорее, сам архитектор волен решать, будет называть он своё сооружение мавзолеем, либо нет.

Comment: Как много полезной информации !

Answer (score 0):

Мне видится, что гробница - более широкое понятие.

Гробница — форма захоронения, при которой останки покойного хранятся внутри сооружения, а не под ним, как в случае надгробия. Этот термин соответствует латинскому «sepulcrum», греческому «крипта», английскому «tomb».

Это **архитектурное сооружение или саркофаг,** вмещающие тело умершего и увековечивающие его память. Таковы древнеегипетские **пирамиды**, **скальные и купольные** гробницы средиземноморских и азиатских стран, **античные и позднейшие мавзолеи**, известные с древности **саркофаги**.

**Мавзолей – это архитектурное сооружение**, носящее ритуальный погребальный характер. Происхождение слова «мавзолей» относится к середине IV века до н. э. Первое погребальное сооружение было возведено в честь карийского царя Мавсола на территории современной Турции. Мавзолей в Геликарнасе представлял собой трехуровневое сооружение. Венчала постройку знаменитая статуя в виде колесницы царя Мавсола. 
 https://www.syl.ru/article/397332/otvet-na-vopros-o-tom-chto-takoe-mavzoley

Мавзолеем сейчас называют **монументальное сооружение с отсеком для хранения останков умершего и одним или несколькими залами.** Залы могут использоваться в качестве поминальных помещений. Мавзолей также может состоять из комплекса сооружений с останками умерших.

Так что и Мавзолей Ленина - гробница, и пирамиды фараонов - гробницы. Мавзолеи как раз в основном строились в виде пирамиды, так что это синонимы в отличие от шахтовых гробниц ( тип погребального сооружения в виде узкой и глубокой шахты из каменной породы), курганов, склепов.

Comment: А почему Вы причислили к гробницам саркофаг? Он ведь, как гроб, сам находится в гробнице, а не является ею. Любопытный факт: изначально гробы египетских покойников саркофагами назвали археологи. Слово это переводится как "пожиратель плоти". Оно в корне неверно, поскольку египтяне использовали эти предметы как раз для сохранения мумифицированных тел для загробной жизни и называли, разумеется, иначе. Но слово саркофаг прижилось.

Comment: Потому что саркофаг и есть " небольшая гробница у народов древности; в более широком смысле — любой архитектурно и художественно оформленный гроб" . Архитектурный словарь. Источник: ttps://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3  И другие словари говорят то же самое. Много саркофагов в виде храмов

Comment: Спасибо. Обратился к источником. Видимо, греки так называли гробницы в целом (пожирателями плоти), а египтянам от этой традиции уже "досталось" и вот так прижилось.